# How to Determine if Google Maps Tiles have Loaded

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I am using the Google Maps API in my iOS application. At the end of a session the map zooms out and captures a screenshot. Unfortunately at the moment, often the map doesn't have time to load all the tiles exposed by the zoom before taking the screenshot.

I see that Apple's MKMapView has an `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` delegate. Is there something similar provided in the Google API?

Answer (score 8):

The Google Maps SDK for iOS has a method called mapViewDidFinishTileRendering that is called when the map finishes rendering.

```
-(void)mapViewDidFinishTileRendering:(GMSMapView *)mapView{
    //TAKE THE SCREENSHOT HERE
}
```

Also, don't forget to set the delegate.

Answer (score 6):

iOS SDK has a function **mapViewSnapshotReady** you can use referansing protocol **GMSMapViewDelegate**

Description on reference:

> Called when map is stable (tiles loaded, labels rendered, camera idle)
>   and overlay objects have been rendered.

```
 func mapViewSnapshotReady(_ mapView: GMSMapView) {
        // map ready to use
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Google Maps Javascript API, you can use event listener for [various UI events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events), for example the `tilesloaded` event.

However, the Google Maps iOS SDK does not have any event listener. You have to use `GMSMapViewDelegate` delegate methods to detect the UI events. For your situation, I think the [mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#af1129dee4fcef90292d96c0aa7764ced) might help you.

Comment: I'm using this method already to capture the screenshot after the map has zoomed to the appropriate scale. Unfortunately this doesn't include updating the map tiles, I was wondering if there was an alternative specific to the loading of the tiles really.

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API has `tilesloaded` UI event, but not in the iOS SDK.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad. Thanks for the information nonetheless.